# How to create multiple new columns based on multiple conditions of other columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, organization, columnsorting

I am trying to figure out how to create new columns based on other columns and insert another column's value as observations in the newly created columns.
Not sure how to clearly explain this in words so I will show an example.

Basically my data looks like this:

| code | spec | grid | month | day | depth | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 31 | 1 | 6 | 17 | 5 | 1 |
| 01 | 33 | 1 | 6 | 17 | 5 | 2 |
| 01 | 45 | 1 | 6 | 17 | 10 | 15 |
| 02 | 45 | 12 | 6 | 17 | 10 | 34 |
| 02 | 45 | 12 | 7 | 19 | 15 | 1 |
| 03 | 31 | 15 | 8 | 27 | 15 | 30 |
| 03 | 33 | 16 | 9 | 13 | 20 | 34 |
| 03 | 31 | 18 | 10 | 17 | 25 | 100 |

My dataset has 2,514 rows.

The 'spec' column is the species code. I would like to create new columns with the actual species name (for each species code) and its respective number as observations(rows).

For example (simplified/mock data for privacy purposes).
Let's say the species code: 31 == mosquito, 33 == lion, 45 == fish....etc.
I would like my data to end up like this:

| code | mosquito | lion | fish | grid | month | day | depth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 17 | 5 |
| 01 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 17 | 5 |
| 01 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 1 | 6 | 17 | 10 |
| 02 | 0 | 0 | 34 | 12 | 6 | 17 | 10 |
| 02 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12 | 7 | 19 | 15 |
| 03 | 30 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 8 | 27 | 15 |
| 03 | 0 | 34 | 0 | 16 | 9 | 13 | 20 |
| 03 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 10 | 17 | 25 |

1. New column with the name of the species for each unique species code (there's probably about 15 species in my data so should have ~15 new columns)
2. Each species should have its respective 'number', if the species was not counted it should have a '0'
3. The 'number' and 'spec' columns can get deleted after this is all set and done.
   *Of course, the data needs to align to its respective day, month, code, grid, etc. so nothing else is changed/modified from original data

I have looked online for a few hours but I haven't been able to find a clear answer...
I have found simpler solutions but not something that meets my question.

I have played around with case_when, if_else, and sapply but can't seem to make it work.
I hope this question is clear. Happy to clarify further.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: How are your species mapped to `spec`? Do you have a lookup table?

Comment: Not really. The species names and their respective codes are in a really old pdf file with 500+ species found in my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(spec = case_when(
      spec == 31 ~ 'mosquito', 
      spec == 33 ~ 'lion', 
      spec == 45 ~ 'fish',
      TRUE ~ NA_character_),
      id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = spec, values_from = number) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 9
#>    code  grid month   day depth    id mosquito  lion  fish
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     6    17     5     1        1     0     0
#> 2     1     1     6    17     5     2        0     2     0
#> 3     1     1     6    17    10     3        0     0    15
#> 4     2    12     6    17    10     4        0     0    34
#> 5     2    12     7    19    15     5        0     0     1
#> 6     3    15     8    27    15     6       30     0     0
#> 7     3    16     9    13    20     7        0    34     0
#> 8     3    18    10    17    25     8      100     0     0
```

Note that you need to map your other species to the `spec` number inside `case_when`

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data from question in reproducible format:**

````r
``` r
df <- structure(list(code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), spec = c(31L, 
33L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 31L, 33L, 31L), grid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 
12L, 15L, 16L, 18L), month = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L
), day = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 27L, 13L, 17L), depth = c(5L, 
5L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 25L), number = c(1L, 2L, 15L, 34L, 
1L, 30L, 34L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df
#>   code spec grid month day depth number
#> 1    1   31    1     6  17     5      1
#> 2    1   33    1     6  17     5      2
#> 3    1   45    1     6  17    10     15
#> 4    2   45   12     6  17    10     34
#> 5    2   45   12     7  19    15      1
#> 6    3   31   15     8  27    15     30
#> 7    3   33   16     9  13    20     34
#> 8    3   31   18    10  17    25    100
````

Comment: Two small hints: (1) I don't think the `id` column is necessary. (2) You could use `pivot_wider`s `value_fill` argument and spare the `mutate()` part. :-)

Comment: @MartinGal thanks - I forgot about `value_fill`. The `id` is necessary to prevent rows 1 and 2 from merging though, since all fields are equal. If the OP is prepared to set up a lookup table as you suggest, then your join is the better option here.

Comment: Yes, I did need that id portion of the code since some repeat

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "spec") %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = "number", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(code, mosquito, lion, fish, grid, month, day, depth)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 8
  code  mosquito  lion  fish  grid month   day depth
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 01           1     0     0     1     6    17     5
2 01           0     2     0     1     6    17     5
3 01           0     0    15     1     6    17    10
4 02           0     0    34    12     6    17    10
5 02           0     0     1    12     7    19    15
6 03          30     0     0    15     8    27    15
7 03           0    34     0    16     9    13    20
8 03         100     0     0    18    10    17    25
```

I used two data frames: Your shown data

```r
structure(list(code = c("01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "03", "03", 
"03"), spec = c(31, 33, 45, 45, 45, 31, 33, 31), grid = c(1, 
1, 1, 12, 12, 15, 16, 18), month = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
    day = c(17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 27, 13, 17), depth = c(5, 5, 
    10, 10, 15, 15, 20, 25), number = c(1, 2, 15, 34, 1, 30, 
    34, 100)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    code = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), spec = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), grid = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), month = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), depth = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

and a data.frame for converting `spec` into the real species name:

```r
structure(list(spec = c(31, 33, 45), name = c("mosquito", "lion", 
"fish")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    spec = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the confusion but I do not have two data frames. The first table in my question refers to what my data looks like right now, the second table in my question is what I want it to look like/what I want to end up with. So I guess I need to use pivot_wider in some way... Thanks for showing how to change the column names as well.

Comment: @FishyFishies "My" `df1` reflects your shown data, `df2` needs to be set up to map `spec` to a real name. This information has to be provided somehow.

Comment: So I tried this and it almost worked... except since there's code, grid, months, days that repeat for the same species I get some rows like this: c(3,3,3).... @Allan Cameron's code worked perfectly